# Ruby Mechanize Check Box, Submit and Displaying Fields Afterwards

Tags: ruby, mechanize

Here is my Ruby Mechanize code and commented near the end is where I'm stuck with the checkbox, selecting the second submit on the page, and displaying some fields after the clicking second submit button.  I've used the [documentation](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Form.html) and searched around and found several ways to do a checkbox.  One of them may be working but I'm not able to select the second submit in the form and view fields to see.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(URL)

#Grab form
surescripts_form = page.form_with(:action => 'Login.aspx?timeout=true')

#Fill in login and password
surescripts_form.LoginIDTextBox = Username
surescripts_form.PasswordTextBox = Password

#Select the user profile form
surescripts_user_form = page.form_with(:name => 'form1')

FirstName = FirstNameVariable
LastName = LastNameVariable
DEA = DEANumberVariable
NPI = NPINumberVariable

surescripts_user_form['ctl00$CPHMainContent$TxtFirstName'] = FirstName
surescripts_user_form['ctl00$CPHMainContent$TxtLastName'] = LastName
surescripts_user_form['ctl00$CPHMainContent$TxtDEA'] = DEA
surescripts_user_form['ctl00$CPHMainContent$NPI'] = NPI
surescripts_user_form['ctl00$CPHMainContent$TxtAddressLine1'] = AddressLine1
#surescripts_user_form['ctl00$CPHMainContent$TxtAddressLine2'] = AddressLine2
surescripts_user_form['ctl00$CPHMainContent$TxtCity'] = City
surescripts_user_form['ctl00$CPHMainContent$DdlState$StateList'] = "New York"
surescripts_user_form['ctl00$CPHMainContent$TxtZip'] = Zip
surescripts_user_form['ctl00$CPHMainContent$TxtPrimaryPhone'] = PrimaryPhone
surescripts_user_form['ctl00$CPHMainContent$TxtFax'] = Fax
#surescripts_user_form['CPHMainContent_CblServiceLevel_1'] = 1
#surescripts_user_form['CPHMainContent_CblServiceLevel_2'] = 1

#Need help with this Check Box
#surescripts_user_form['CPHMainContent_CblServiceLevel_6'] = 1
#surescripts_user_form.checkbox_with(:value => '32').check
#surescripts_user_form.checkbox_with(:name => /CPHMainContent_CblServiceLevel_6/).check

#Need help with this Submit
#page = agent.submit(surescripts_user_form['ctl00$CPHMainContent$BtnSave'])
#page = surescripts_user_form.submit(page.form_with(:action => /.*/).submits[22])
page = agent.submit(surescripts_user_form, surescripts_user_form.buttons.last)

#Need help with displaying fields on the next page
pp page.body
pp surescripts_user_form

#Displays all my input values
File.open('form_log.txt', 'w') do |f|  
  # use "\n" for two lines of text  
  f.write surescripts_user_form.fields.each { |d| puts d.name }
end  

#Displays html of the page
File.open('page_log.txt', 'w') do |f|  
  # use "\n" for two lines of text  
  f.write page.labels_hash()
end
```

Comment: I may be having the same problem, having recently updated the mechanize gem

Comment: I got help from Eric :)  It was my misunderstanding